# How to communicate list of factories across DLL boundary using extern "C" function

Tags: c++, dll, collections, return-value, factory

I am loading DLLs dynamically at run-time. Compatible DLLs will have a function that returns a collection of [pointers to] plugin factory objects (that will subsequently supply the main application with instances of their respective plugins).

The function is using a C ABI to mitigate name mangling and enable discovery*.

In *pseudo code* it would look something like this:

```
Collection<Factory*> GetFactories();
```

The factories are static objects allocated by/in the DLL.

What is the best/proper way to do this?

- GetFactories() returns a pointer to some kind of Factory collection?
- GetFactories() returns a pointer (or a reference?) to a struct that holds [a pointer to] an array of Factories and the size of the array?
- GetFactories() returns a vector of Factory pointers (raw? unique_ptr?)?
- GetFactories() returns an array of Factory *objects* (and is complemented by a GetFactoryCount)() function that should be called first to get the size)?
- GetFactories(Factory[]&) is called with a reference to a preallocated Factory array (the size of which is first obtained by GetFactoryCount()? Or called with a reference to a preallocated vector?
- etc etc etc (I'm sure there are many more alternatives)...

I've only been coding in C++ for a couple of weeks now and sometimes it's a complete mindf*ck to try to get an overview of all the relevant considerations and obscure rules and special cases one is seemingly required to be aware of. What can be done across boundaries, with different heaps, with compiler incompatibilities, scopes, what is supported / can be exposed / destructed where, raw pointers, smart pointers, references, copying, "best practices" vs MY case (which always seems to be some edge case).. It feels like trying to tame a wild, unruly animal.

Anyway - I'll be grateful if anyone has any tips here. I have been searching around, believe me, but either the answers are contradicting each other, some guy's personal preference or they are incomplete with regards to my situation.

**Will it? And does using a C ABI (`extern "C"`) circumvent the problem of compiler incompatiblity?*

Comment: From the guts I'd say choosing a `std::vector` (or `std::set`) of `std::unique_ptr<IFactoryInterface>` seems to be the most appropriate choice, but you don't explain enough on your requirements to make it a final decision!

Comment: Can std::vector be returned from a C style function across a DLL boundary?

Comment: No, of course not for a [tag:c] API natively (directly), but using a vector as an internal implementation detail for such API, might simplify some necessary pitfalls about correct memory management though. You can expose a (currently valid) reference to an array of (raw) pointers held in that vector though.

Comment: Well, that was the question: How to communicate _the list of factories across a DLL boundary using an extern "C" function_ (not how to represent a collection on either side). So your suggestion is that the DLL returns a _plain reference_ to its vector's internal array of raw pointers to factory objects? How will the main app know the size of the array - will it have to query the DLL for it separately?

Comment: _'will it have to query the DLL for it separately'_ Yeah, that might be one of the design restrictions you'll face with exposing a C-style API. You **can** expose C++ classes using shared libraries as well, but if you'll need to fit your library for C-style plugin interfaces, there's not other choice IMHO.

Comment: Yes, as stated, all these plugins are loaded dynamically at run-time. The main app knows nothing of them until the containing DLL is loaded and queried, so I have to go for extern "C" (as far as I know). Regarding getting the size of that array - I could instead return a reference to a well-known struct containing both the size of the array and the reference to it (that was indeed one of the proposed approaches in the question).

Comment: OK, I see (your second suggestion, right?). But using `std::vector` or another appropriate STL container might **still** be helpful for the implementation details. That's what's my point is all about!